# Powershell Script cycles through machines but hangs if one loses network temporarily

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that parses a txt file which is full of machine names, then one by one, it creates a session to the system, runs a few commands, and moves to the next system. The script usually take about 10-30 seconds to run on each system depending on the case encountered in the script.

Once in a while the system that is currently being checked will lose the network connection for some various reason.  When this happens the console starts writing yellow warning messages about attempting to reconnect for 4 minutes and then disconnects the session when it cannot reconnect.
Even if it establishes the connection again within the 4 minutes, it doesn't do anything after that, it's like the script just freezes. It won't move on to the next system and it doesn't stop the script, I have to manually stop it, or if i manually run the script, i can hit control+c to break out of the current loop, and it then moves on to the next machine in the list.

Is there any way to break out of the current loop if a warning is encountered so it can move on to the next machine? That would be my ideal solution. thanks!

Script is simple..

```
foreach($server in Get-Content .\machines.txt) {
    if($server -match $regex){

invoke-command $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ScriptBlock{
command1
command2
command3
}
}
```

this is what happens

```
PS C:\temp> .\script.ps1
machine1
machine2
machine3
machine4
machine5
WARNING: The network connection to machine5 has been interrupted. Attempting to reconnect for up to 4 minutes...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to machine5 ...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to machine5 ...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to machine5 ...
WARNING: The network connection to machine5 has been restored.
```

But it never goes on to machine6

Comment: It may be simpler to let `Invoke-Command` manage that. `$Servers=Get-Content .\machines.txt|Where{$_ -match $regex};Invoke-Command $Servers -ea SilentlyContinue -ScriptBlock {...`

Comment: thanks.. will test this out, but do you think it will resolve the issue here? not sure it changes anything really

Comment: Take a look into the ```-warningaction``` on ```invoke-command```, might be worth letting it faile or continue so it can carry on processing the rest

Comment: tried -WarningAction:Stop , but sadly it did not work

Answer (score 0):

When i work remotely with multiple machines i usually start the processes on the machines in parallel. So i have less impact when single machines are timing out. I use powershell 7 ForEach-Object -Parallel Feature for this [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-
feature/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/)

Try something like this:

```
$Credential=Get-Credential

#all Necessary parameters must be in the Object i give to ForEach Object
$myHosts = @(
    #Hosts i want to connect to with values i want to use in the loop
    @{Name="probook";cred=$Credential;param1="one_1";param2="two_1"}
    @{Name="probook";cred=$Credential;param1="one_2";param2="two_2"}
)

$var1="one"
$var2="two"

$myHosts | ForEach-Object  -Parallel {
    #Variables outside of this "Parallel" Loop are not available. Because this is startet as separate SubProcess
    #All Values come from the Object i piped in the ForEach-Object 
    $myHost=$_ 
    #This is written to your local Shell
    Write-Host ("Computer: "+ $env:Computername)
    Write-Host $myHost.param1
    Write-Host $myHost.param2
    Write-Host $myHost.cred.UserName

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $myHost.Name -Credential $myHost.cred -ArgumentList @($myHost.param1,$myHost.param2) -ScriptBlock {
        #Variables outside of of this Invoke Command Script Block are not available because this is a new Remote-Shell on the remote Host
        #Parameters in Ordner of -Argument List
        param($param1,$param2)

        #Do your things on the Remote-Host here

        #This is not Visbible -> it is only written on the "remote Shell"
        Write-Host $env:Computername

        #Here you get Back Values from the remote Shell
        $env:Computername
        $param1
        $param2
    }
} -ThrottleLimit 5
```

Comment: problem is that i have each machine writing back to a csv file sequentially, and when all machines report back i am then manipulating the CSV and emailing it out. if i run all in parallel then how will i know when all are done, so i can then email the csv file out?

Comment: @JohnnyCakes, Depends on how much data you are collecting, however when I do my machine sweeps I'll collect and dump the data into the regular powershell data pipeline.  aka just output the value you want to capture.  Then redirect the entire output of your parallel process to where ever you want for it to go.  Then when the parallel process is done you will get your CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm his is indeed a Problem.

You could experiment with:

- Start-Job
  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.1)
- Get-Job (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-job?view=powershell-7.1)
- Receive-Job (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job?view=powershell-7.1)

So you have more control what the processes do.
You start Background Jobs with Start-Job. Start-Job deliveres Job Objects Back -> save them in a array or variables

With Get-Job you see all Jobs currently Running

with Receive-Job you get back the output from a Job so far. You can use receive-Job to get back all PSObjects a Background Job has written.

Cannot explain in Detail, but this woul be another try i would do for this job.